# WebSocket from HTTPS website to different port, self-signed certificate

Tags: .net, angular, websocket, rxjs, self-signed-certificate

I am facing issues when trying to connect from a browser via WebSocket to a server.
Website is hosted on a default port (80, 443, configurable - this is s selfhosted intranet application for multiple customers).
We use self signed certificates and it needs to be running with self signed cert (if possible)
All works well on without SSL HTTP website (port 80), WS websocket (custom port let's say 8090)

When SSL is turned on, hence web running on HTTPS (port 443) and WebSocket on WSS:// (same port 8090). The connection is not opened.
I am using rxjs WebSocketSubject to create the connection in the browser.

I am also making sure that the SSL cert is bound to both ports (443, 8090)
URL ACL is set (netsh http add sslcert ipport....)

Any idea what the problem is?
Is it because self-signed/insecure certificates are not accepted for websocket connection?
Is the problem with SSL the different port between the website and webSocket?

Comment: Any errors in the network console?

Comment: No, generic error message only - Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://192.168.1.6:8090/
The same problem in Chrome, Edge.
The error is probably just s timeout, it show error after 30s. So the question really is whether some of the points are mentioned do not work with SSL connections (self-signed cert, different port, or the combination of both). Maybe I forgot to do some config change in the OS, like is the SSL cert binding to the URL that I do for both the website and I now tried for the WebSocket port too (netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8090....)